# Comparing length of strings in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Hi I'm trying to compare the length of each word in a sentence. I converted this sentence into an array but then I'm lost in my codes.
I tried 2 methods - for loop and reduce(), but neither worked. What happened in my code?

Reduce() => This one gave me undefined when I try to run the function. I gathered it's because of the max.length/word.length, but how can I turn my string into length using reduce()?

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let brokenDown = str.split(' ')
  
  brokenDown.reduce((max, word) => {
    return Math.max(max.length, word.length)
  })
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

For loop => This one gave me the length of the first word rather than the maxLength. I'm guessing probably because my var strLength is not an array, but how to make it into an array containing the length of each index?

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let brokenDown = str.split(' ')
  for(let i = 0; i < brokenDown.length; i++) {
    var strLength = brokenDown[i].length
  }
  return Math.max(strLength)
}

findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

I know this should be very basic and simple and i can't wrap my head around what went wrong here.

Comment: _"This one gave me undefined"_ - Because the function never returns anything. You have to `return` the result of the `.reduce()` call. Also `max` in the callback will be a string on the first call and a number after that. Have another look at how [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and its callback works

Comment: ooh i feel like an idiot with the reduce() function thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second approach you posted, you aren't setting the max properly. You are setting a variable called `strLength`, but your `Math.max` is outside the loop. So you will never get the maximum value unless it happens to be the last word in the array.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let brokenDown = str.split(' ')
  let mxLen = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < brokenDown.length; i++) {
    mxLen = Math.max(mxLen, brokenDown[i].length);
  }
  return mxLen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const maxLength = (str) => {
  const words = str.split(' ');
  const lengths = words.map((word) => word.length);
  return Math.max(...lengths);
}
console.log(maxLength('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `Math.max` approach, first extract he lengths of each word and then pass those to the `Math.max`.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let brokenDown = str.split(' ')
  let lengths = brokenDown.map(word => word.length);

  return Math.max(...lengths);
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

---

If you want to go the `for` loop approach, you will have to keep a maxLength while looping, and update it as the loop encounters longer words.

```js
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let brokenDown = str.split(' ')
  let maxLength = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < brokenDown.length; i++) {
    const wordLength = brokenDown[i].length;
    if (wordLength > maxLength) {
      maxLength = wordLength;
    }
  }
  return maxLength;
}

console.log(findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: _"reduce is not very usefull in this scenario"_ - Why? Why would `.map()` be better?

Comment: How is your answer(first snippet) different than the answer that I posted?

Comment: @Andreas you are right, it was not a valid statement. Reduce would work by using a running max like in the for loop.

Comment: @ParveshKumar looks like it is not different. We just happened to be writing our answers at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

not so hard to do...

```js
const findLongestWordLength = str =>
  str.split(' ').reduce((r,s)=>Math.max(r,s.length), 0)



console.log( findLongestWordLength("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog") )
```

Comment: Sorry - I still don't quite understand why the initial value of 0 is necessary here if I were to set the previousValue in the reduce function as r.length? I read through the MDN and still have no idea.

Comment: @tommy-ling the zero is the first value for `r` and also  the default value if str is empty

Comment: hey I understand that the 0 is the first value for r, but why can't i just put (r.length, s.length)? in this case, the initial r.length would be the length of the first string in the array(which is index 0), no? And especially in this case the first string is not empty

Comment: @tommy-ling  if you want to program properly, you must provide for the possibility that the string may be empty. Otherwise read my code again: the variable `r` is numeric, numbers do not have a `length` property in javascript, and `Math.max(r.length,s.length)` will throw an error

Comment: ooooh!!!! I got it! since r is the previous iteration and in our case the previous iteration is always a NUMBER!!!